# Angular 2 - http get return wrong object

Tags: angularjs, angular, angular-promise, observable, angular-http

I'm using @angular/http get to fetch data from server, here is my code :

```
private _currentPT: any;
public phongtroDetailChange = new Subject();

layPhongtro(id: number): Promise<any> {
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  this.http
    .get(Constants.apiUrl + 'phongtro/' + id, { headers: Constants.headers })
    .map((resp: Response) => resp.json())
    .subscribe(resp => {
      console.log(resp);
      // if (!resp.result) {
      //   this._currentPT = resp;
      //   this.phongtroDetailChange.next(true);
      //   resolve(resp);
      // } else {
      //   this.handleError('layPhongtro', resp.result);
      //   reject(resp.result);
      // }
    },
    error => this.handleError('layPhongtro', error));
});
}
```

When I commented code like that, the property "tiencoc" of resp has right value which means its value is 0, here is the picture of console.log

https://i.stack.imgur.com/7oYGW.png

But when I uncommented, the value of "tiencoc" is the same as property "giatien", now its value is 1000000, here is picture of console.log when uncommented

https://i.stack.imgur.com/rGxdI.png

I dont know why ? Pls help me, thank you so much

P/s: I have tested with POSTMAN and the resp is OK, which means "tiencoc"'s value is 0

Comment: Can you uncomment and change `console.log(resp)` into `console.log(JSON.stringify(resp));` and tell what the value of tientoc is then?

Comment: Hi @echonax, the value of "tiencoc" is now 0, can you explain to me the reason ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a fiddle for demo: https://jsfiddle.net/Lg6L8n2m/ (guess what the value is before you look at the log :))

As I've mentioned it the comment when you `JSON.stringify` the response object you are printing that value (because strings are immutable in js). But without stringify, `console.log` works actually somewhat "asynchronously", `console.log` prints the latest value that the object has.

So you are changing the `tientoc` to be `1000000` somewhere in your code after your `console.log`. And console.log prints you the latest value. From what I see it might be in the block where you subscribe to your Subject `phongtroDetailChange`

I suggest reading Immutability in javascript about this problem.

Comment: @NhatDang no problem. Check out the fiddle on my answer too to see what I mean.

Comment: yes, you're right, I subscribe Subject phongtroDetailChange in child component and change the value, you can read my answer :)

Comment: Sorry, can you read my answer and explain me more :(, I still can't get it,

the currentPT of ptService  = resp in layPhongtro function
and then in child component I store it with this.currentPT, I just change value of this.currentPT, variable of child component only

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @echonax, I am reading "Immutability in javascript" now :), And by the way I have found that in child component I have done this:

```
constructor(private ptService: PhongtroService) {
    this.init();
  }

ngOnInit() {
    this.ptService.phongtroDetailChange.subscribe(result => {
      if(result) {
        this.init();
      }
    });
}
init() {
  this.currentPT = this.ptService.currentPT;
  if(!this.currentPT.tiencoc || this.currentPT.tiencoc === 0) {
     this.currentPT.tiencoc = this.currentPT.giatien;
  }
}
```

I have stored the currentPT of ptService in currentPT of child component (this.currentPT), and then change value of this.currentPT

and in ptService

```
private _currentPT: any;
get currentPT(): any{
return this._currentPT;
}
set currentPT(pt) {
this._currentPT = pt;
}
```

and in layPhongtro function above

```
this._currentPT = resp;
this.phongtroDetailChange.next(true);
```

Some how, some way the code in child component also affects this resp

Comment: Can you update your question with where you subscribe to `phongtroDetailChange` please?

Comment: @echonax: I have updated my answer, I subscribe to phongtroDetailChange in ngOnInit() of child component

Comment: well ok then, there's your answer. You are changing the value of the object when you do the `.next(true)`. So that's why `tientoc` comes as 0 but logs as 100000

Comment: But the strange thing here is I changed the value of property "tiencoc" of currentPT, which belongs to only child component, but then It affects the property "tiencoc" of resp in layPhongtro function too !

Comment: Don't think this like Java. If you assign an object to another object in js, when one of them changes the other one also change since they have the same reference

Comment: Oh really !, so I have to start learning JS all over again :(, this thing I don't know yet, Thank you so much @echonax  :D

Comment: No problem:) but dont forget this only happens in mutables